# BlackBerry 10 Native SDK - Writing Text Files

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I am battling to write some data to a simple text file 
Here is my code:

```
QFile file(app->applicationDirPath() + "/data/testfile.txt");

if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
    QTextStream stream(&file);
    stream << "DATA HERE \n";
}
```

The app compiles and runs fine.

Just I cant find the file, or more likely: it is not being created

Where am I going wrong? :)

Thanks

*Extra Info:* 
**Run:** on my device (BlackBerry Z10) 
**IDE:** QNX IDE (Native SDK) / (Cascades) 
**Example code is located in:** TestApp::TestApp(bb::cascades::Application *app)
: QObject(app)

Comment: When I try:  
    `QDir home = QDir::home();
    QFile file(home.absoluteFilePath("testAppFile.txt"));` The same thing happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I kinda stumbled upon the answer myself:

```
QFile file(QDir::currentPath() + "/shared/documents/yourfile.txt");

if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
    QTextStream stream(&file);
    stream << "DATA HERE \n";
}
```

Turns out each application has access to its own working directory. So the file was being created, I just could not see it on the device:

making the path: "/shared/documents/" made the file in a place where I could see it in the file manager

(hope this helps anyone who has a similar problem in the future)

[This is a useful link](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/bb10/com.qnx.doc.native_sdk.devguide/com.qnx.doc.native_sdk.devguide/topic/accessible_folders.html), which explains the directories & current path.

Comment: That's what I am looking for.